# SQL - Select query

Tags: sql

Here is my simulated data

```
Table 1               Table 2
Column 1  Column 2    Column 1  Column 2   
111       AAA         111       AAA
111       BBB         111       BBB
222       AAA         111       CCC
...                   222       AAA  
                      ...
```

I want the 'children' (Column2) of Table 1 in Table 2 which are absent in Table 1.   In this case I would need `'111 CCC'`.

Comment: dont be lazy and show us desire result too. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I agree that the question is lazy as it shows absolutely no effort, but he does have an expected result.

Comment: @Siyual words arent same as a formated table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use CONCAT. The way I read your question, you are not just checking that CCC is in table 1, but rather, you want to know if the combination of 111 AND CCC is in table 1. You can do that as follows:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table2
WHERE CONCAT(column1, column2)
NOT IN
(SELECT CONCAT(column1, column2)
 FROM table1)
```

Comment: Bad idea because you cant use the index. much better is a right join with both columns

Comment: What do you mean the index?

Comment: to optimize that query, OP should create on `INDEX(col1,col2)`  using `CONCAT` will avoid the use of index

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
Select  T2.*
From    Table2  T2
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    Table1  T1
    Where   T1.Column1 = T2.Column1
    And     T1.Column2 = T2.Column2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it with "not in":

```
select column1, column2 
from table2 
where column2 not in (select column2 from table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 
        on t1.Col1 = t2.col1 
       AND t1.Col2 = t2.Col2
WHERE t1.Col1 is NULL 
  AND t1.Col2 is NULL
```